# UWP - Use Data Template inside style in GridVIew

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

An error when trying to click on the item in Grid View. I have such style setter:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridViewItem">
                <ListViewItemPresenter x:Name="Root" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CompletedDataTemplate}">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">                                        
                               <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Item" 
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.15" BeginTime="00:00:00.2000000"/>

                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetName="Item" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.15" BeginTime="00:00:00.2000000"/>
                                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="471"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>                                   
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DisabledStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Enabled"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ListViewItemPresenter>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

And also I have such Data Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompletedDataTemplate">
    <Grid x:Name="Item" Width="471" Height="303">

        <Grid Height="265" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="../Assets/Fantastic-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg"/>
        </Grid>

        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="20" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="21" FontFamily="../Assets/Fonts/GothamPro.ttf#Gotham Pro" Foreground="White" TextLineBounds="TrimToCapHeight"
                   VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

        <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="267" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Opacity="20">
            <Grid.Background>
                <AcrylicBrush TintColor="Black" TintOpacity="200"/>
            </Grid.Background>
            <TextBlock FontSize="64" Text="Open" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And when I start my app, templates and binding work perfectly but I don't know how to set the target name of storyboards to my data template elements. Any idea? Maybe I should use other solution?

Generally, I have such problem: I need to use different styles in my grid view and different Data Templates. I have already tried to use the Visual States in my data template but seems that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to use different styles in my grid view and different Data Templates.

It can't resolve to that name because that name is local to the DataTemplate. You could move the Storyboard within the DataTemplate and start it when the Grid is tapped.

To achieve this effect, you need to use the [ControlStoryboardAction](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/ControlStoryboardAction) in [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors).

Please see the following code sample for rference:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CompletedDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="Item" Width="471" Height="303">
            <Grid.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="storyboard">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Item" 
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" To="1.15" BeginTime="00:00:00.2000000"/>

                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.4" Storyboard.TargetName="Item" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" To="1.15" BeginTime="00:00:00.2000000"/>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.5" Value="471"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                    <Media:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboard}"/>
                </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Grid Height="265" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Image Stretch="Fill" Source="../Assets/Fantastic-Full-HD-Wallpaper.jpg"/>
            </Grid>

            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Height="20" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="21" TextLineBounds="TrimToCapHeight"
               VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

            <Grid x:Name="grid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="267" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" Opacity="20">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <AcrylicBrush TintColor="Black" TintOpacity="200"/>
                </Grid.Background>
                <TextBlock FontSize="64" Text="Open" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then, if you want to apply different DataTemplate for GridView's item, you could use [DataTemplateSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datatemplateselector).